# Tomcat 7 with security manager enabled and Spring in Servlet 3.0 mode context loading

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I have a Spring MVC application with `web.xml` set up, which was running fine under Tomcat 7 with security manager enabled. Now I've converted the application to JavaConfig and Servlet 3.0 code-based configuration (no `web.xml`) and I got this exception:

```
[ 05 Jun 2014 05:48:27 ] ERROR: Context initialization failed!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run(ContainerBase.java:140)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
        ... 29 more
Jun 05, 2014 5:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

If you look into Spring, you'll see that Spring Servlet 3.0 environment **only** invokes `ContextServletListener` constructor with an argument, a constructed context (see `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer`). But during investigation I found out that empty constructor of `ContextServletListener` is invoked too! What I saw in `jdb`:

```
pool-2-thread-2[1] where
  [1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.<init> (ContextLoaderListener.java:60)
  [2] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (native method)
  [3] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [4] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  [5] java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:526)
  [6] java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:374)
  [7] org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance (DefaultInstanceManager.java:125)
  [8] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener (ApplicationContext.java:1,291)
  [9] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (native method)
  [10] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  [11] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  [12] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
  [13] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade$1.run (ApplicationContextFacade.java:851)
  [14] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (native method)
  [15] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.executeMethod (ApplicationContextFacade.java:848)
  [16] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.invokeMethod (ApplicationContextFacade.java:796)
  [17] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.doPrivileged (ApplicationContextFacade.java:767)
  [18] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener (ApplicationContextFacade.java:652)
  [19] org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.registerContextLoaderListener (AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:59)
  [20] org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.onStartup (AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:47)
  [21] org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup (AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:66)
  [22] org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup (SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
  [23] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal (StandardContext.java:5,249)
  [24] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:150)
  [25] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal (ContainerBase.java:866)
  [26] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000 (ContainerBase.java:128)
  [27] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run (ContainerBase.java:151)
  [28] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run (ContainerBase.java:140)
  [29] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (native method)
  [30] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild (ContainerBase.java:840)
  [31] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild (StandardHost.java:615)
  [32] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR (HostConfig.java:958)
  [33] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run (HostConfig.java:1,599)
  [34] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:471)
  [35] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:262)
  [36] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1,145)
  [37] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  [38] java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:744)
```

If you look at this stacktrace, you'll see that on frame 18 `ApplicationContextFacade.addListener` method was called and it was passed a constructed instance of `ContextLoaderListener` (with the context already set up). Then yada-yada-yada and on stack frame 8 we reach `ApplicationContext.addListener` which receives just a class name and constructs `ContextLoaderListener` *afresh*! So what happens is this (taken from `ApplicationContextFacade.java`):

```
649    @Override
650    public <T extends EventListener> void More ...addListener(T t) {
651        if (SecurityUtil.isPackageProtectionEnabled()) {
652            doPrivileged("addListener",
653                    new Object[]{t.getClass().getName()});
654        } else {
655            context.addListener(t);
656        }
657    }
```

Clearly see it constructs a new instance instead of passing on the already constructed one. `isPackageProtectionEnabled` has the following condition:

```
private static boolean packageDefinitionEnabled =
         (System.getProperty("package.definition") == null &&
            System.getProperty("package.access")  == null) ? false : true;
```

So I can work around this problem by turning off package protection in Tomcat. So my questions are:

1. Why is it done this way?
2. How to remediate this situation without work-arounds and turning security off (neither completely nor package protection)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it was done this way, but it appears to be a bug with Tomcat <=7.0.42. According to tomcat 7 [changelogs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html):

> Tomcat 7.0.43 (violetagg)
>
> When using a security manager, ensure that calls to the ServletContext
> that are routed via an AccessController.doPrivileged block do not
> result in a call to a different underlying method on the
> ServletContext. (markt)

Simply upgrade Tomcat to any later versions, which has the proper implementation.